# Solution fails to build when using OutDir with MsBuild

Tags: c#, .net, build, msbuild

We have several .Net 4.0 solutions that all depend on assemblies built by one specific solution, our Server.sln (I guess Shared.sln would have been a better name for it).  Our build process first builds the Server.sln to a Binaries directory using the [MsBuild OutDir parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.workflow.activities.msbuild.outdir.aspx), and then subsequent solutions to subdirectories (e.g. Binaries\Client, Binaries\Web, etc.), again using the OutDir parameter to specify the path to the appropriate subdirectory. This allows us to easily publish our separate applications to different places. This works fine for all of our solutions, except a new API.sln that we created.

Like the other solutions, API.sln references some DLLs built by the Server.sln, but the actual compile error I get is that one project (we'll call it Project1) cannot find a reference to Project2.  Project1 and Project2 are both projects in API.sln, and Project1 references Project2 via a project references; not a dll file reference.  Also, Project2 does not have any external dependencies either; the only references it has are to *System*, *System.Core*, and *System.Runtime.Serialization*.

Everything works if I set the OutDir to just be the Binaries directory, but I don't want to do that as then all of the API.sln assemblies get mixed with ALL of the Server.sln assemblies, which makes deploying just the API.sln assemblies harder.  When I set the OutDir to be Binaries\API then I get the build error saying that:

```
The name '[Project2 Class Name]' does not exist in the current context [Path to Project1.csproj]
```

I checked though and the Project1.dll and Project2.dll assemblies are both getting created to the Binaries\API directory, so I'm not sure why this error is getting generated.  Our TFS build server has this problem, but I can also recreate it on my local machine by calling MsBuild on the .slns with the same parameters. Any ideas?

Here are the two msbuild commands that I'm using to actually do the builds:

Build the Server.sln:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe /nologo "C:\PlatformAPIBuild\BuildProcessTests\Sources\RQ4.Server.sln" /nr:False /fl /flp:"logfile=C:\PlatformAPIBuild\BuildProcessTests\Sources\RQ4.Server.log;encoding=Unicode;verbosity=normal" /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:ReferencePath=C:\PlatformAPIBuild\BuildProcessTests\Binaries  /p:OutDir="C:\PlatformAPIBuild\BuildProcessTests\Binaries\\" /p:Configuration="Release" /p:Platform="Any CPU" /p:VCBuildOverride="C:\PlatformAPIBuild\BuildProcessTests\Sources\RQ4.Server.sln.Any CPU.Release.vsprops"
```

Then build the API.sln:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe /nologo "C:\PlatformAPIBuild\BuildProcessTests\Sources\IQ.Platform.PublicAPI.sln" /nr:False /fl /flp:"logfile=C:\PlatformAPIBuild\BuildProcessTests\Sources\IQ.Platform.PublicAPI.log;encoding=Unicode;verbosity=normal" /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:ReferencePath=C:\PlatformAPIBuild\BuildProcessTests\Binaries  /p:OutDir="C:\PlatformAPIBuild\BuildProcessTests\Binaries\Platform.PublicAPI\\" /p:Configuration="Release" /p:Platform="Any CPU" /p:VCBuildOverride="C:\PlatformAPIBuild\BuildProcessTests\Sources\IQ.Platform.PublicAPI.sln.Any CPU.Release.vsprops"
```

And [here is the log file](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=5B8A9A60D4190040!38050&authkey=!AJvQmxRkWslaxXM) from the API.sln build.  You'll notice that it has errors like,

```
Warning as Error: Reference to type 'IQ.Platform.Framework.WebApi.Model.Hypermedia.AccessControl' claims it is defined in 'c:\PlatformAPIBuild\BuildProcessTests\Binaries\Platform.PublicAPI\IQ.Platform.Framework.WebApi.Model.dll', but it could not be found
```

but the file it says isn't there, is actually there when I look for it after the build fails, and you can see that one of the first things it does at the top of the log file is copy that assembly to that path, so I'm not sure why it can't find it. The IQ.Platform.Framework.WebApi.Model is the Project2 in my discussion above.

[Here is the log file](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=5B8A9A60D4190040!38051&authkey=!AHphPB28Xj5I7kE) from the API.sln build with all of the Test projects removed, so that only one error remains, which will hopefully make looking through the log file a little easier. And [here is the same log, but with diagnotic verbosity](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=5B8A9A60D4190040!38052&authkey=!AGWuZmRo3WFZJoo).

Comment: can you please check and make sure that your compile and build order for projects in the solution is Project2 -> Project1 -> Project API?

Comment: Project build order is correct; I checked both in Visual Studio and in the MsBuild log file. I just noticed though that Project2 is actually included and built in Server.sln as well. So Project2.dll first gets built to the Binaries directory when the Server.sln is built, and then again to the Binaries\API directory when the API.sln is built. Not sure if this makes a difference, but thought it might be worth pointing out since it seems to work when I tell the API.sln to build to the Binaries directory.

Comment: can you try something, instead of binaries folder can you output that in a completely different folder, OutputSlns and then OutputSlns/Project1, OutputSlns/API etc.... see what happens!

Comment: When I change Server.sln to build to Binaries\Server and then try to compile the Client.sln or API.sln to Binaries\Client and Binaries\API, they both say that they cannot find some assemblies. Looks like it is necessary for Server.sln to be in the base directory.

Comment: Can you post some of code and scripts? Might give a better view!

Comment: Updated post with additional info and log file

Comment: Initial thoughts are it sounds like referencing issue within your tests. Can you re-reference the projects rather than it's dlls used in the tests? And also try using fakes for your tests. Dlls from your binary folder might be getting deleted and recreated.

Comment: First off, thanks for all your help so far Shriroop :)  Unfortunately I didn't write any of this code; I'm just responsible for getting it to build properly and promoting it from Dev to Test :P  I tried removing and re-adding all of the references to IQ.Platform.Framework.WebApi.Model, all as project references as they were before; didn't help. So I removed all of the test projects, but still have one error by one other "required" project that references that project. Any other thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: Trying to figure out stuff again, by reading the post and the log file again but struggling. Can I request you to post the log file after you have removed the integration tests, so that the output log can be viewed?

Comment: Ok, updated post with the other log files.

Comment: Change MSBuildToolsVersion in ValidateToolsVersion Target. Logfile - "Target "ValidateToolsVersions: (TargetId:3)" in file "C:\PlatformAPIBuild\BuildProcessTests\Sources\IQ.Platform.PublicAPI.sln.metaproj" from project "C:\PlatformAPIBuild\BuildProcessTests\Sources\IQ.Platform.PublicAPI.sln" (entry point):
Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(MSBuildToolsVersion)' == '2.0' and ('$(ProjectToolsVersion)' != '2.0' and '$(ProjectToolsVersion)' != '')) was evaluated as ('4.0' == '2.0' and ('' != '2.0' and '' != ''))." Read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397428(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Make sure you are using 'Fakes'/'Fake Assemblies' for your test projects; path - C:\PlatformAPIBuild\BuildProcessTests\Sources\IQ.Platform.PublicAPI.RQ.v1.Resources\FakesAssemblies

Comment: I did a grep over the source control folder and all projects are using 'ToolsVersion="4.0"', and also tried providing the /ToolsVersion:4.0 switch to MsBuild from the command line when building to force it to use v4.0, but still failed with the same error.

Comment: Can't think about anything else, right now. If I do will let you know. Sorry could not help any further.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for all your help Shriroop. I'll at least give you an upvote for effort!